# How to convert Hyperlink in formula field

Tags: formula-field, hyperlink

As Salesforce is disabling the use of JavaScript in Hyperlink function in formula fields, as per this documentation: [Hyperlink Formula Fields for JavaScript Disablement](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249336&type=1)

I am working on changing one formula field.

I have created a custom link with `Execute JavaScript` functionality. But custom links will be displayed at the bottom of the page.

Is there any alternative way where I can get this link on random place on the page layout?

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: They are not disabling the use of hyperlinks in formula fields. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249336&type=1

Comment: Sorry, I mean eliminating Javascript in Hyperlink function. Currently,  I am working on changing the functionality on alternative way. Is there any alternative apart of custom link? where i can get link on any other section on page layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to place a button anywhere in layout. Can be done by a inline page which simply redirects, but it would be an overkill for such a simple requirement.

Possible solutions are mentioned in documentation: [Hyperlink Formula Fields for JavaScript Disablement](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249336&type=1). Quoting from it:

> **What action do I need to take?**
>
> We recommend that admins begin reviewing their use of JavaScript in
>   hyperlink formula fields and migrate to alternative solutions. This
>   critical update is enabled for all orgs on the auto-activation date of
>   October 30, 2017. Here are some possible workarounds.
>
> 1. **Create a Custom Button or Link executing JavaScript**
>
>    - Create custom buttons or links executing OnClick JavaScript
>    - *Supported in Salesforce Classic only*
> 2. **Create a Lightning Experience Quick Action**
>
>    - Create JavaScript in a Lightning Experience component that can be executed though a Quick Action button
>    - *Supported in Lightning Experience only*
> 3. **Create a custom Visualforce Page to redirect to the correct URL**
>
>    - If there is a client-side conditional logic to be executed to decide the link to which the user needs to be directed, create an
>        empty Visualforce page and an Apex controller. Pass the required
>        values from the link to controller, execute the logic to decide the
>        URL in controller method and perform the redirect.
>
> We recommend that you test this update in a sandbox or Developer
>   Edition org. Check the behavior of the HYPERLINK function in formula
>   fields.

Based on where you need to execute this action, you have these options.